# How to configure spring config server search path to pull config from custom directory structure

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-config-server, configserver

I'm trying to set up Spring Cloud Config to get the application parameters bootstraped from a git repo.
For our use case, each project can have specific parameters for each customer, and each of those can have their own environments as well. So the configuration repo structure looks like this:

```
> projectA/
>     customerx/
>         customerx-dev.yml
>         customerx-uat.yml
>         customerx-prod.yml
>     customerz/
>         customerz-dev.yml
>         customerz-uat.yml
>         customerz-prod.yml
```

This is the configuration I have for Config Server:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        git:
          uri: git@repo.com/myconfigrepo.git
```

I tried config server with the following request but got a not found error.

`curl http://localhost:8080/projectA/customerx/dev`

Is there a specific way I have to configure the searchPaths parameter on config server?

Answer (score 0):

Our developers use the following approach.

`{application} placeholder is the SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_NAME`

```
spring-boot-config-server:
    environment:
      - spring.cloud.config.server.git.uri=https://github.com/org/repo.git
      - spring.cloud.config.server.git.username=username
      - spring.cloud.config.server.git.password=${CONFIG_SERVER_GIT_ACCESS_TOKEN}
      - spring.cloud.config.server.git.search-paths=foo/bar/{application}
      - spring.cloud.config.server.git.default-label=branch-name

component:
    environment:
      - SPRING_CONFIG_IMPORT=configserver:http://spring-boot-config-server:1234/
      # will use folders for customerx and customery
      - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_NAME=customerx,customery
      - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=customer_rules
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your answer. Please provide more details about your solution. Code snippets, high quality descriptions, or any relevant information would be great. Clear and concise answers are more helpful and easier to understand for everyone. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77045362/edit) your answer with specifics to raise the quality of your answer. For more information: [How To: Write good answers](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Happy coding!